# Why would the order of Laravel API routes affect how they work

Tags: laravel

I have the following routes setup with an auth prefix.

```
// Workspace Routes
        Route::get('workspace/region-setup-status', 'WorkspaceController@regionSetupStatus');
        Route::get('workspace/regions', 'WorkspaceController@getRegions');
        Route::get('workspace/{id}', 'WorkspaceController@show');
        Route::post('workspace/store-regions', 'WorkspaceController@storeRegions');

        Route::get('workspace/operations', 'WorkspaceController@getOperations');
        Route::get('workspace/operation-setup-status', 'WorkspaceController@operationSetupStatus');
        Route::post('workspace/store-operations', 'WorkspaceController@storeOperations');

        Route::get('workspace/inspection-area-setup-status', 'WorkspaceController@inspectionAreaSetupStatus');
        Route::post('workspace/store-inspection-areas', 'WorkspaceController@storeInspectionAreas');
```

In this setup the get route for `'workspace/operation-setup-status'` refuses to return anything from the method.

However if I reorder the routes and move the 'operation' routes to above the 'region' routes everything works as expected?

Why would it behave this way?

Comment: Also, consider chaining where method to validate route parameters like so `Route::get('workspace/{id}', 'WorkspaceController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Comment: Thanks did not not know you can do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Laravel try to do a pattern matching with the routes, with the order which the routes are declared, and the first that make a match, it runs that one, so your `workspace/operation-setup-status` is managed by

```php
Route::get('workspace/{id}', 'WorkspaceController@show'); // $id === "operation-setup-status"
```

but if you move your

```php
Route::get('workspace/operation-setup-status', 'WorkspaceController@operationSetupStatus');
```

before the one with `{id}` , it match correctly in the right order